# Changing position of Nivo slider

Tags: css

I'm attempting to change the width of the Nivo slider on my blog. Currently it spans the entire width of the page wrapper and I'd like to put a left and right margin so it is centered and aligned with the navigation bar and not stretching out to the sides. (I will be resizing the images to fit once I can figure out how to change the width of the wrapper. I've tried changing the width under the css section below. The width changes, however the slider and image are then align hard left. I've also tried sticking in margin tags but it doesnt seem to affect it. I'm stumped.

[My Blog](http://www.popglitch.com)

```
#slider-wrapper-full { width:1000x; 
                         height:400px; 
                         overflow:hidden; 
                         padding-top:10px; }

#slider-wrapper-full  #slider { width:1000px;  
                            height:400px; 
                            background:url(images/loading.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%; }
```

I changed this:
    .nivoSlider { position:absolute; 
                  overflow:hidden;  }

to this:
    .nivoSlider { width: 900px; 
                  overflow:hidden;  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the width of the nivoSlider class

```
.nivoSlider {
      width: 900px;
}
```

Comment: I think something might be over-riding it because nothing seems to change.  It currently says the following and I tried adding in width but it doesnt seem to affect it.                                                                 .nivoSlider { position:absolute; 
              overflow:hidden;  }